# How to have smooth transitions when using animator.Play() Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I have a smooth transition when using animator.Play(), could be using crossfade be the trick, so i have 2 states, not connecting by any transitions, and I am playing them by using animator.play(),

when i use animator.crossfade(), it transitions to frame 1, and stops, so how can i fix this

Comment: Do you mean scene transition (transition between scenes?)

Comment: No, im talking about in a character animation, so i have 2 states, not connecting by any transitions, and I am playing them by using animator.play()

Answer (score 0):

Use [Animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime.html) to run animation with smoth transition with specified delay
Use [Animator.IsInTransition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.IsInTransition.html) check to not interapt other animations transitions

e.g.

```
    _animator.IsInTransition(0))
    {
        return;
    }

    _animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime(animationName, 0.3f);
```

Comment: is animationName the name of the current or the next animation to be played?